# python Popen works on linux but doesn't on windows

Tags: python, subprocess, adb

I would like to run the same code on linux and windows. below code works on linux but not on windows!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess

def runcmd(cmd,show=True):
    print("cmd:" + cmd)
    try:
        p = subprocess.Popen(cmd,shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
        retval = p.communicate()[0]
        print(retval)
        return retval.decode('utf-8')
    except:
        print("cmd error:" + cmd)
        pass
    return ""

def main():
    runcmd("adb shell 'find /data/ -type f ! -empty'")
    return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The output from windows10:

```
cmd:adb shell 'find /data/ -type f ! -empty'
b'/system/bin/sh: find /data/ -type f ! -empty: inaccessible or not found\r\n'
```

Comment: Looks like Popen worked successfully on Windows.

Comment: Popen works, but not work for this specific command maybe!

Comment: `inaccessible or not found` is returned by `adb shell`, which means whatever Android device you're trying to access is returning an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put the entire adb shell command in a single argument. Use:

```
runcmd("adb shell find /data/ -type f ! -empty")
```

You may have different versions of `adb` on Linux and Windows. The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#shellcommands) mentions that the way the arguments are processed changed in Android Platform-Tools 23.

Comment: awesome, just try it and works! and verified the command actually works on powershell but not work on cmd window, python use cmd I guess so report error!  adb version the same in powershell and cmd window. what's the reason powershell works?